# Are any finitely generated reflexive module a 2nd syzygy?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Are any finitely generated reflexive module a second syzygy?

(I´m thinking especially in normal noetherian domains)

More general...

Are any divisorial lattice a second syzygy?
(I´m thinking especially in Krull domains)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over a normal domain (in fact, you only need Gorenstein in codimension 1, being second syzygy and reflexive are equivalent). This is Theorem 3.6 of Evans-Griffith "Syzygies" book.